# ScrollView - Adding dynamic rows from inflated xml layout

Tags: java, android, dynamic, scrollview, xml-layout

I currently have a scrollview which I am adding rows to by inflating another xml layout. This is all working as it should and the row are all appearing correctly.

The issue I am having is that I am not sure how I can detect which button has been selected.

I have shown some example code for 1 on by buttons, simply put when this button is selected it toggles between 2 images. However, whenever I press the button it always automatially toggles the bottom rows button rather than the row in which the button has been selected.

Is there a way this can be implemented whilst still inflating a view to be used as a row (I do not want to dynamially create the rows, as this gets very messy)?

```
ScrollView scrollWeapons = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollWeapons);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
int i = 0;

for(final Weapon w : Game.Weapons)
{
    View view = new View(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menuweapons_row, null);

    btnSelected = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnSelected);
    btnSelected.setId(i);
    btnSelected.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EquipUnequip(w.WeaponID());
        }
    });
}

private void EquipUnequip(int WeaponId)
{
    if(Game.Weapons.get(WeaponId).CharacterID() == ChrSelected)
    {
        btnSelected.setImageResource(R.drawable.eqip_but_idle);
    }
    else
    {
        btnSelected.setImageResource(R.drawable.eqip_but_press);
    }
}

ll.addView(view);
i++;
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use a listview with a custom adapter for that?

Comment: I read that in general it is better to use a ScrollView

Comment: The opposide is correct if your data uses the same view: In a scrollview every view has to be created and hold in memory. Listviews recycle views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onClick` method of `OnClickListener` has a parameter `v`. The value of `v` will be the `View` that was clicked, i.e. the `ImageButton`. All you have to do now is pass the `View` to `EquipUnequip`:

```
...
btnSelected.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EquipUnequip(w.WeaponID(), (ImageButton)v);
    }
});
...

private void EquipUnequip(int WeaponId, ImageButton btnSelected) {
    if(Game.Weapons.get(WeaponId).CharacterID() == ChrSelected) {
        btnSelected.setImageResource(R.drawable.eqip_but_idle);
    } else {
        btnSelected.setImageResource(R.drawable.eqip_but_press);
    }
}
```

---

**PS:** This part seems a bit non-sensical to me:

```
View view = new View(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menuweapons_row, null);
```

Why do you create a new `View` just to do nothing with it and replace it with the result from the `LayoutInflater`?

---

#### Edit

If you really need the row of the View (and it never changes) here are 2 alternatives:

1. Save row in the `OnClickListener`

   ```
   class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
       private final int rowIndex;
       MyOnClickListener(int rowIndex) {
           this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
       }

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // do something with rowIndex
       }
   }
   ```

   and use it instead of your anonymus class
   or simply add a final variable outside your anonymus class:

   ```
   // currentRowIndex calculated by your program
   // i.e. incremented in every iteration
   final int rowIndex = currentRowIndex;
   btnSelected.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // do something with rowIndex
       }
   });
   ```
2. Add the info as tag to the button (`currentRowIndex` would be of type `int`):

   ```
   btnSelected.setTag(currentRowIndex); // attach Integer data to the view
   btnSelected.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           int rowIndex = (Integer)v.getTag();
           // do something with rowIndex
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: So stupid of me should have spotted that it works thanks

Comment: I do actually have one follow up question, I forgot that within my dynamic code i also have an ImageView, that when clicked need to act in the same way the ImageButton does. How can i possibly detected the ImageButton row when seleteing the ImageView on the same row?

Comment: @LandLPartners: You can add a field to the Listener (non-anonymus class) or add a final variable in the loop (so that it can be accessed from the anonymus listener class), use [`setTag` + `getTag`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) of the `View`, ...

Comment: I have tried this before, but cannot quite get it to work could you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Give the View parameter of onClick() to EquipUnequip(), cast this to ImageButton and use it. Otherwise you get the last created button.